# How can I copy/rename/overwrite image using PHP, submit and radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, php

I am just starting out with PHP, and I am trying to make a way for a client to be able to change an image using radio buttons and form submission.  My intention is for one of 2 image files (Open/Closed.jpg) to be copied and renamed to another location (images/status/Status.jpg) so that coding isn't needed to make the change.

The "new" image will then be used elsewhere.  I have tried various copy() and rename() calls, but with no luck.  Below is the code I am working with.  I feel my problem lies with the submit call, but all things I have tried have not worked.  So I am back to my original code (below) trying for a fresher start with help from seasoned users/programmers.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<title></title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

<?php 
// define variables and set to empty values
$WinterStatusErr = "";
$WinterStatus = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["WinterStatus"]))
     {$WinterStatusErr = "Status is required";}
   else
     {$WinterStatus = test_input($_POST["WinterStatus"]);}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<p><span class="error"><font color="red"><b>* required selection</b></font></span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   <input type="radio" name="WinterStatus" <?php if (isset($WinterStatus) &&          $WinterStatus=="open") echo "checked";?>  value="Open">Open
   <input type="radio" name="WinterStatus" <?php if (isset($WinterStatus) && $WinterStatus=="closed") echo "checked";?>  value="Closed">Closed
   <span class="error"><font color="red"><b>* <?php echo $WinterStatusErr;?></b></font></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" <?php
if ($Winterstatus == "Open")
    { copy ("images/Open.jpg", "images/status/Status.jpg"); }
   elseif ($Winterstatus == "Closed")
    { copy ("images/Closed.jpg", "images/status/Status.jpg");}
?>> 
</form>

<?php echo $WinterStatus ?>
</body>
```

Comment: <font> tags went out of use 10 years ago. You should be careful where you scoop your code.

Comment: basic debugging: `copy()` and its cousin filesystem functions return boolean FALSE on failure. You don't even bother checking for that. Did you confirm that your paths are correct? Did you check if the permissions on the source file/dir and the target file/dirs are correct? Plus WHY are you embedding the copy logic **INSIDE** your submit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in php you can use exec() to execute a command. on linux the "cp" command should do what you are asking.  Permission/security issues will be a problem though, so i would recommend just changing a variable to the new image rather then actually moving it...a lot simpler and safer -- if I knew where you reference the image I could help you figure that out.

Comment: Nelag...Thank you for pointing out simple mistakes.  Once I removed the If from the submit and fixed the capitalization, it is working.  The code is just as I have on the site, just with Meta data removed.  To Diodeus, I wrote the code and the reason for font imbedding here is due to this being for mobile web so I didn't need grand.

Comment: I'm glad its working...though to be fair it was not me but redFro that pointed out the simple mistakes :).  That being said I am grateful that I now have the coveted minimum 15 credz to upvote helpful answers.

Comment: Sorry redFro, you were the one who suggested that.  I fell to the perils of using a phone to view and reply.  I have taken all suggestions given by redFro and Nelag and have made proper corrections.  Now using variables and moved the if statement out of the Submit statement.  Thanks again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

first remove the if statement from your submit input, then change $Winterstatus in the if statment to $WinterStatus.